# Only allowing ints and floats to be entered into field with javascript and mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I require some sort of direction with how to only allow either an int or float to be entered into a form input field. The validation must happen on the key up event. The problem I am having is that when entering, for example, `1.2` the check within the keyup event function sees `1.` which is not a number.

Here is the code I have:

```
document.id('inputheight').addEvent('keyup', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.toFloat();
    if (this.value == 'NaN') {
        this.value = 0;
    }         
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply clean up the value of the field on keyup. Something like this should do the trick:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/([^\d.]+)?((\d*\.?\d*)(.*)?$)/, "$3");
```

The regular expression instantly replaces the value with the first numeric string it encounters.

```
([^\d.]+)?  // optionally matches anything which is not
            // a number or decimal point at the beginning

(\d*\.?\d*) // tentatively match any integer or float number

(.*)?$      // optionally match any character following
            // the decimal number until the end of the string
```

Comment: This works really really well. Very good. I must master regex.

Comment: It bears mentioning that when you do this, you must also ensure that there is a corresponding server-side check, as malicious users can and  will bypass that check.